# Отправка всех значений select на сервер

Tags: html, php

Не получается отправить значения из всех select'ов, на сервер приходит только значение первого select'а

```
<select type="text" name="n1">
    <option value="1">Да</option>
    <option value="0">Нет</option>
</select>
<select type="text" name="n2">
    <option value="1">Да</option>
    <option value="0">Нет</option>
</select>
<select type="text" name="n3">
    <option value="1">Да</option>
    <option value="0">Нет</option>
</select>
```

Comment: серверную часть в студию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пуля вылетает, проблема на вашей стороне: [пример в песочнице](http://jsfiddle.net/Sv54G/99/) :D

Answer (score -1):

Отсылайте на сервер `"Select.selectedIndex"`